# Using Jasmine spies to test the calling of functions

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I cannot work out how to get Jasmine to check if functions within my testing function are getting called. I know I have to use a spy, but I clearly don't understand the implementation of spies, as it is currently not working.

My function looks something like this:

```
function templates($rootScope, ShareStats) {
    return {
        _writeToStore: function(tmpl, tmplOld) {
            $rootScope.store.templates.save(tmpl);
            if (tmplOld) {
                ShareStats.update(tmpl, tmplOld);
            } else {
                ShareStats.saveAll();
            }
        },
    }
}
```

My test is looking like this:

```
describe('Unit: templates', function() {
    var Templates,
        rootScope,
        tmplOld = {...},
        tmplNew = {...};

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('myApp');
        inject(function($injector) {...});
    });

    describe('Templates._writeToStore', function() {
        it('should save object to $rootScope.store.templates', function() {
            var _writeToStore = Templates._writeToStore(tmplNew, tmplOld);
            spyOn(_writeToStore, 'rootScope.store.templates.save');
            _writeToStore(tmplNew, tmplOld);
            expect(rootScope.store.templates.save).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
        it('should call ShareStats.update() if tmplOld is passed', function() {
            var _writeToStore = Templates._writeToStore(tmplNew, tmplOld);
            spyOn(_writeToStore, 'ShareStats.update');
            _writeToStore(tmplNew, tmplOld);
            expect(ShareStats.update).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You spy isn't quite correct.

```
spyOn(_writeToStore, 'rootScope.store.templates.save');
```

should be:

```
spyOn(rootScope.store.templates, 'save');
```

ie the object where the function is located as the first argument and the function name as the second.

The problem then is to have a reference to the rootscope

Comment: rootScope is injected in through the injector function